# Media Temple VE is over memory (happens quickly after restart)

Tags: memory-usage, mediatemple

I checked `top` and everything *looks* okay (but I'm kind of a noob, so ya).

I ran a `$ free -m` and it says 338/924 is free which doesn't seem so bad. However, MT reporting says mem was at 190% so I restarted the server and now it's already saying mem is at 110%.

Either way, how do I find the culprit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running top is a quick & easy way to find out what is using the most memory. (ve) Server's are development servers that are highly customizable & are only recommended to those with strong server administrations skills and command line knowledge. 
I found your account & see that a tech has responded to your support request with some more in depth info about your memory usage. If you have any more questions, feel free to respond to the support request & we'll get back to you ASAP!

Comment: I gave you a +1 for awesome service. On top of that though, I want to actually learn how to do this myself if only for curiosity sake.

Comment: The culprit was that I was running a VE with insufficient memory. I upgraded from 128g to 512g and everything is A-OK.